# Flutter Scrollable Container

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I want to build this specific UI, I don't think that this is an AppBar on the top. I think it is a container, the top part is scrolled with the screen but the container with the text is scrolled. Let me know if anyone can help me achieve this.

[image: UI Screenshot]

Comment: Can you include what you've tried so far

Answer (score 1):

```
class PageName extends StatefulWidget {
  const PageName({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PageNameState createState() => _PageNameState();
}

class _PageNameState extends State<PageName> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('title'),
        actions: [
          IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.close), onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          }),
        ],
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          // your children
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Alternatively, if you have the body as 1 widget, you can use `SingleChildScrollView`

```
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: YourBodyWidget(),
      ),
```